# Remove specific plugins and themes from the Dashboard->Updates page

Tags: plugins, themes, dashboard

Is there a way to remove specific plugins and themes from showing up from the WordPress Updates page?

Comment: [Easy Update Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/stops-core-theme-and-plugin-updates/) plugin will do it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two hooks you can use: 'site_transient_update_plugins', and 'site_transient_update_themes'.

### Plugins

To disable update for 'fpw-category-thumbnails' plugin, put the following code in functions.php of your theme ( child theme ):

```
function remove_plugin_updates($value) {
    unset($value->response['fpw-category-thumbnails/fpw-category-thumbnails.php']);
    return $value;
}
add_filter('site_transient_update_plugins', 'remove_plugin_updates');
```

If you want to disable updates for all plugins, use the following code:

```
function remove_plugin_updates($value) {
    return null;
}
add_filter('site_transient_update_plugins', 'remove_plugin_updates');
```

### Themes

To disable update for 'twentytwelve' theme, put the following code in functions.php of your theme ( child theme ):

```
function remove_theme_updates($value) {
    unset($value->response['twentytwelve']);
    return $value;
}
add_filter('site_transient_update_themes', 'remove_theme_updates');
```

If you want to disable updates for all themes, use the following code:

```
function remove_theme_updates($value) {
    return null;
}
add_filter('site_transient_update_themes', 'remove_theme_updates');
```

### Summary

To disable plugin's update, you must know a path to plugin's .php file, relative to '/wp-content/plugins/' folder.

To disable themes's update, you must know a path to theme's folder, relative to '/wp-content/themes/' folder.

### Easy way

To make it all easy, use [Easy Update Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/stops-core-theme-and-plugin-updates/) plugin.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer. If the Easy Update Manager does the same thing as those filters, I was just testing it out and it does remove it from the Updates page but it also completely disables the ability to update the selected items. Are the notifications of updating plugins (Updates page) tied directly to the _ability_ of updating them? Or is there a way just to disable their display in the Updates page?

Comment: Both, filters, and the plugin will allow you to disable update info, and ability to update a plugin / theme. You can turn it on and off, when you want it. It is much easier to do it with the plugin, because you don't need to edit functions.php, for every change.

Comment: Okay, in order to satisfy my requirement, it sounds like I can just use an if statement based on roles or permissions before listing which plugin to disable.